# Select an element inside div with multiple elements a same class onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

I have installed Joomla 3 and Im trying select an element from multiple elements with the same class, but when I apply onmouseover event on the element, the function affect all elements with same class, I want the function affect to select element (onmouseover element)

```js
function ocultarDatos() {
  var itemk2 = document.querySelectorAll(".encabezado");
  for (var i = 0; i < itemk2.length; i++) {
    itemk2[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="catItemImage" onmouseover="ocultarDatos();">
  <a href="<?php echo $this->item->link; ?>" title="<?php if(!empty($this->item->image_caption)) echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->image_caption); else echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->title); ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->item->image; ?>" alt="<?php if(!empty($this->item->image_caption)) echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->image_caption); else echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->title); ?>" style="height:auto;" />
  </a>
  <a rel="author" href="<?php echo $this->item->author->link; ?>"><img class="globo" src="<?php echo $this->item->author->avatar; ?>" alt="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->author->name); ?>" >
  </a>
</span>
```

```html
<div class="catItemView groupLeading">
  <div class="encabezado">
    <div class="catItemBody">
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemContainer itemContainerLast" style="width:12.5%;">
    <div class="catItemView groupLeading">
      <div class="encabezado">
        <div class="catItemBody">
          <div class="clr"></div>
          <div class="clr"></div>
          <div class="clr"></div>
          <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have fixed it with CSS:

```
.encabezado { background: white; padding: 0px 15px; display:none; } .itemContainer:hover .encabezado { padding: 0px 15px; display:block; top: 150px; z-index: 100; }
```

With the effect i was searching for. Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `var itemk2 = $(this).find(".encabezado");`

instead of `var itemk2 = document.querySelectorAll(".encabezado");`

This should achieve the effect you are looking for

Comment: Hi Glen, thanks for the reply, but doesn work :(
`function ocultarDatos(){
        var itemk2 = $(this).find(".encabezado");
        for(var i=0; i<itemk2.length; i++){
  itemk2[i].style.display = "none";        
        }
    }`

Comment: Could you clarify what specifically you are trying to do? Is it just to hide a single `encabezado` element, or is it to hide all `encabezado` elements?

Comment: Yes, it just to hide a single encabezado element, with a onovermouse event

Comment: Fernando, you need some way to specify the encabezado element that you'd like to hide. Could you give a little info about what you're trying to achieve? I assume it has something to do with hiding images but I'm not quite sure. If so, you may be better off with a function that hides the encabezado elements when _they_ are hovered over

Comment: Hi Glen, I Have fixed it with CSS

.encabezado {
 background: white;
 padding: 0px 15px;
 display:none;
 }
 
   .itemContainer:hover .encabezado {
 padding: 0px 15px;
 display:block;
 top: 150px;
 /*position: absolute;*/
 z-index: 100;
 } 

With the effect i was searching for. 
Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass event object in callback. and then you can use that event object to find current object and its child such as element with `encabezado`class in your case.

Try below code.

**HTML**

```
<span class="catItemImage" onmouseover="ocultarDatos(event);">
   ... ...
</span>
```

**JS**

```
function ocultarDatos(event){
    var encabezado = event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.encabezado');
    encabezado[0].style.display = "none";
};
```

---

**Working Demo:**

```js
function ocultarDatos(event){
    var encabezado = event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.encabezado');
    encabezado[0].style.display = "none";
};

function ocultarDatosOther(event){
    var encabezado = event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.encabezado');
    encabezado[0].style.display = "";
};
```

```html
<div onmouseover="ocultarDatos(event);" onmouseout="ocultarDatosOther(event);">
    MouseOver on me.
    <span class="encabezado">
        and i will hide
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, jad-panda, run this error in firebug...
TypeError: encabezado[0] is undefined
encabezado[0].style.display = "none";

Comment: try `currentTarget` instead of `target`. i have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks jad but run this TypeError: encabezado[0] is undefined
 

encabezado[0].style.display = "none";

/joomla/ (línea 46, col 4)
TypeError: encabezado[0] is undefined
encabezado[0].style.display = "";

Comment: did you try with `currentTarget ` ? and check in DOM is that `. encabezado` element is really present in child HTML of `<span class="catItemImage">` ?

Comment: Same happens... with currentTarget, and element is in child HTML because when I use document.querySelectorAll('.encabezado');
It detects all "encabezado" elements and hide all

Comment: create jsfiddle and send me HTML of your `<span class="catItemImage">` element

Comment: sorry, jad, I do not know how do that

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="catItemView groupLeading">
  <div class="encabezado">
    <div class="catItemBody">
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemContainer itemContainerLast" style="width:12.5%;">
    <div class="catItemView groupLeading">
      <div class="encabezado">
        <div class="catItemBody">
          <div class="clr"></div>
          <div class="clr"></div>
          <div class="clr"></div>
          <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```